# jquery goto next element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to have two separate links go to the next/previous item in an li.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="previousButton">
    <h1 id="previous"><a href="#previousBox" class="previous">&lt;</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="nextButton">
     <h1 id="next"><a href="#nextBox" class="next">&gt;</a></h1>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$('.next').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left - paddingWidth}, 750);
    $('li').previous().fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    $('li').next().fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
});

$('.previous').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left - paddingWidth}, 750);
    $('li').next().fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    $('li').previous().fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
});
```

But what I'm missing is the actual function to select the next item in the list, how can I do this? I was thinking perhaps changing the destination of the link each time the nextButton is clicked, but I'm not sure how about to do it. Any ideas? I'd prefer not to use any external jquery libraries if not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, from an SEO aspect - you cannot use two <h1> tags in one page.

--

To your question:

you can combine the $.index() function and the $.eq() function.

```
var NextLi = $('ul.SomeUL').eq($('li.SelectedLi').index() + 1);
```

Good Luck

Comment: I'm not too concerned with SEO, but thank you for the h1 catch. But how would I assign that variable to the next link every time that the button is clicked?

Comment: Would you put the UL code here so I can help you with that more specificly?

Comment: `<ul id="mainContent">
<li class="homeBubble"><a name="box1" id="box1">hi there</a></h1></li>
<li class="addBubble"><a name="box2" id="box1">hi there</a></h1></li>
<li class="addBubble"><a name="box3" id="box1">hi there</a></h1></li>
</ul>`

Comment: the problem is that the a names and ids are going to be made dynamically, so I cannot always call them by name

Comment: this <h1> bothers me =]
use .prev() as the previous() function - as a start!
you should have a variable counter, which rises each time a next button is clicked and the opposite way as the prev button gets clicked.
Now you can know the current li item's index...!
and catch it by the eq() function

Comment: -1 for "cannot use two `<h1>` tags in one page". HTML5 *encourages* the use of `<h1>` elements where they would make sence (I.E. a blog with a list of `<articles>`). You haven't linked to any source proving that search engines (google) dock points for multiple h1 elements.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the h1's.. I stripped them for you and left a few ending tags in there. I don't quite understand what you mean about using the .prev() as the previous function.. I knew to do that, but my whole question is about the implementation of it. As far as the variable counter goes, how would I translate that to a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current node in the handler and use that to decide the next node like this:
[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwVGV/)

```
$('a.next, a.previous').click (liScroller);

function liScroller (event) {
    var newNode;
    liScroller.oldNode  = liScroller.oldNode  ||  $('#scrollMe li:first');

    event.preventDefault ();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left - paddingWidth}, 750);

    //--- Get the new element, depending on the direction.
    var bGoingBack      = $(this).hasClass ('previous');
    if (bGoingBack) {
        newNode         = liScroller.oldNode.prev ('li');
        if (newNode.length == 0)
            newNode     = $('#scrollMe li:last');
    }
    else {
        newNode         = liScroller.oldNode.next ('li');
        if (newNode.length == 0)
            newNode     = $('#scrollMe li:first');
    }

    //--- Do the switcheroo.
    liScroller.oldNode.fadeTo ("slow", 0.5);
    newNode.fadeTo            ("slow", 1.0);

    //--- Update stored value.
    liScroller.oldNode  = newNode;
}
```